# When running Swing application with the Spring Framework, Unit tests do not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swing, testing

I am developing a project through the spring framework. I am using JUnit to run unit tests, swing for the GUI. When I run the system, the GUI opens and I can access the database. But when I try to run the tests, I get the following errors.

`Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cs320MtsApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'application'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application' defined in file`

Here is my **runner class**

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class Cs320MtsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    Application application;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Cs320MtsApplication.class).headless(false).run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        application.init();
    }
}
```

**Application** class which is contains swing components.

```
    @Component
    public class Application extends JFrame {
        @Autowired
        private TransferOthersAccount   transferOthers;
        @Autowired
        private Register                register;
        @Autowired
        private CheckBalance            checkBalance;
        @Autowired
        private MainMenu                mainMenu;
        @Autowired
        private ViewTransactionHist     viewTransaction;
        @Autowired
        private Welcome                 welcome;
        @Autowired
        private ChangePassword          changePassword;
        @Autowired
        private TransferOwnAccount      transferOwn;
        @Autowired
        private Login                   login;
}
```

Here is my **example test**

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestUserService
{
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;
    /**
     * The default DB mode is "create"
     * This test creates 2 user and 2 account for each user.
     * This method should be run in order to initialize the DB and work with it for testing purposes.
     */
    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() throws Exception {

        // Creation of first User
        User user = new User("Kerem","Ersan",123456,"07-04-2000","35007269396","kerem.ersan@ozu.edu.tr","5057656825");

        // Creation of first User's first account.
        Account account = new Account(300,user);
        user.getAccounts().add(account);
        account.setUser(user);

        // Creation of first User's second account.
        Account account2 = new Account(200,user);
        user.getAccounts().add(account2);
        account.setUser(user);

        // saves first User information to the DB
        userService.save(user);

        // Creation of second User
        User user2 = new User("Zuhal","Karabas",973100,"05-06-1998","24107854293","zuhaltokgoz@gmail.com.tr","5511768127");

        // Creation of second User's first account
        Account account3 = new Account(1575,user2);
        user2.getAccounts().add(account3);
        account.setUser(user2);

        // Creation of second User's second account
        Account account4 = new Account(1870,user2);
        user2.getAccounts().add(account4);
        account4.setUser(user2);

        // saves second User information to the DB
        userService.save(user2);


    }
    @Test
    public void deleteAllRows()
    {
        userService.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this, some parts may have been misused in the spring, I'm very new in Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)` annotation in your TestUserService class